# What would be the best way to implement SHA512 into my code?

Tags: c#, sql

So I need to store passwords in a SQL database and it would be insecure to store them in plain text. For a variety of reasons, I chose SHA512 to hash the passwords prior to storage. I, for the life of me, can not identify how to take data from a Secure string gained from user input, and hash it using SHA512 (which also means I haven't been able to look into salting it either).

I have seen online that you call a new instance of SHA512 but that it has to be managed (?) but when I try it shows that it is obsolete. Looking further, the wise internet suggested the create method of SHA512... which is also obsolete.

Any help into how I can hash and salt a secure string would be great.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't want to use a well-established [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#identity-providers) instead? There are just _so many pitfalls_ ...

Comment: This was my first port as it is NIST certified. If you have anything that could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you really _need_ your own identity management to meet any Certification requirements, then I'd _urge_ you to hire someone who has done that before and accompanied that successfuly through the certification process. Especially in that case, this is not to be taken lightly. And again: behind every corner lurks an exploit in the dark.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I am not in a position to hire anyone, and I am doing this in .Net Framework.

Comment: Using a cryptographic hash+salt for passwords is outdated. You should use a dedicated password hashing algorithm that is designed to be slow, especially on GPUs, to reduce the risk of brute force attacks. Key derivation functions, like PBKDF2, are sometimes used for this. But see [Hashing passwords in asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: The very fact that you have beginner questions about this tells that an expert is needed here. Maybe you can convince your manager to hire someone? Have you tried talking to your company's IT/ITsec department? Either way the cheapest option probably is to use a well-known identity provider.

Comment: Maybe it helps to not only talk to tech people. There are possibly liability issues etc. So talk to someone whose job it is to prevent being successfully sued.

Comment: I agree with the above but you still need a solution at the end of the day. Why are you using secure strings? Reason I am asking is because you will need to convert them to a normal string to use in any hashing function. Making the use of a secure string a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic hash and salt method using SHA512 and a random salt prepended to the hash.

```
private static string HashAndSalt(string plaintext)
{
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

    using var hasher = SHA512.Create();
    var random = new Random();

    var ciphertextBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext));
    var ciphertextB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertextBytes);
    var salt = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

    var ciphertext = salt + ':' + ciphertextB64;

    return ciphertext;
}
```

You will need to convert your `SecureString` to a normal `string`. Using a `SecureString` is obsolete and should not be used anymore. As the comments mentioned you should look into a dedicated password hashing algorithm such as:

- PBKDF2
- Argon2
- Bcrypt
- Scrypt

Here is an example using `Bcrypt` - it is not too complicated.

First, grab this NuGet package: `BCrypt.Net-Next`

```
private static string BcryptHash(string plaintext)
{
    var ciphertext = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(plaintext, 12);
    return ciphertext;
}
```

You can't however compare the hashes when a user tries to authenticate as you can with SHA512. You need to use Bcrypts 'Verify' function.

```
private static bool BcryptVerify(string plaintext)
{
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(plaintext, hashedPassword);
}
```

Where the plaintext is the `plaintext` password you receive from user input and the `hashedPassword` being the hash you retrieved from the database where the initial ciphertext was stored.

Hope this helps.